# jQuery Mobile text/search change event acts differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery mobile application with change events bound to certain text inputs. The text inputs with the type="search" in particular don't fire on the "change" event like the type"text" text inputs do. Here is a snippet to explain:

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1"> 
    <div  data-role="content">
        <a href="#p2" data-role="button">Go To Page 2</a>
    </div>
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="p2">
    <div  data-role="content">
        <p>This is page2</p>
        <input type="text" id='mytextbox'></input>
        <input type="search" id='mysearchbox'></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#mytextbox').change(function() {
    alert('Hello World!');
});
$('#mysearchbox').change(function() {
    alert('Hello World!');
});
```

Both text inputs are identical other than their id and their type. The text box fires on the change event, the search box doesn't.

The thing I have found is that if the text inputs are located on page 1, everything works as you would expect. So this is a relationship between page changes and the type of text field.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/1644/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this

```
<div data-role="page" id="p2">
    <div  data-role="content">
        <p>This is page2</p>
        <input type="text" id='mytextbox'></input>
        <input type="search" id='mysearchbox'></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this

```
<div data-role="page" id="p2">
    <div  data-role="content">
        <p>This is page2</p>
        <input data-type="text" id='mytextbox'></input>
        <input data-type="search" id='mysearchbox'></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

The difference is I need to specify a "data-type" not a "type".

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to get the change event when doing the searching. `type='search'` has some other events associated. In this case you have to check `onSearch` event. You can check more in this link - [reference](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdvxmhr.php).

Comment: Not really but what you have said however has set off some alarm bells in my head and I have realised what I have done wrong. I will answer myself.